# JAVA Created two objects of each class with complete data using a constructor but getting an error

Tags: java, constructor

I'm trying to create two objects of each Man and Woman class with complete data using a constructor, with constructor that have all possible parameters.

I'm getting an error stating :

> "invalid method declaration; return type required".

My code :

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Man man1 = new Man();
    System.out.println(man.name + "" + man.age + "" + man.address);

    Man man2 = new Man();
    System.out.println(man.name + "" + man.age + "" + man.address);

    Woman woman1 = new Woman();
    System.out.println(woman.name + "" + woman.age + "" + woman.address);

    Woman woman2 = new Woman();
    System.out.println(woman.name + "" + woman.age + "" + woman.address);

    //write your code here
}

private String name = "Mark";
private int age = 23;
private String address = 16527;

public Man(String name, int age, String address) { 
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.address = address;
}

public Woman(String name, int age, String address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.address = address;//write your code here
  }
 }
```

Can someone please help me :(

Answer (score 2):

Your class is named `Solution` which means that your constructor can be named *only* `Solution`. Create separate classes named `Man` and `Woman` and then add your constructors there.

Also, since you are creating an object using default constructor, make sure to add them too in the above mentioned classes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to call `new Man()` or `new Woman()`, you need to create an empty constructor for each class. Alternatively, you can have **no constructor at all** in the class and let java construct the default constructor.

Based on your code, you can only initialize them via the constructor that you have create which are `new Man("Mark", 23, "16527")` and `new Woman("Mary", 23, "16527")`

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem, the cause of the error `invalid method declaration; return type required` is that you are putting the constructor for `Man` and `Woman` inside another (`Solution`) class. They should be defined in their own class. This error you're getting means that the compiler thinks there is a regular method declaration without a return type. It just thinks you made a method called `Man`(with some arguments) and a method called `Woman` (with some arguments).

Additionally, if you want that data to actually be part of the Man or Woman class, you should make sure it becomes part of those objects. You could make a constructor with those arguments or add it through setter methods later. The data won't magically appear in those objects just by constructing them with an empty constructor.

Answer (score 0):

May be your code will be like this:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Man man1 = new Man(); // first way to create object


    Man man2 = new Man("dhiraj",28,"Indore"); // second way to create object
    System.out.println(man2.name + "" + man2.age + "" + man2.address);



    Woman woman1 = new Woman(); // first way to create object



    Woman woman2 = new Woman("dhiraj",28,"Indore"); // second way to create object
    System.out.println(woman2.name + "" + woman2.age + "" + woman2.address);

    //write your code here
}
}



class Man
{
private String name, address;
private int age;

public Man()
{
}


public Man(String name, int age, String address) { 
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.address = address;
}


}

class Woman
{
private String name, address;
private int age;

public Woman()
{
}

public Woman(String name, int age, String address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.address = address;//write your code here
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are new to Java. The code you've provided has a lot of mistakes. 

  (For ex:) **Constructor should have the same name as the class

While defining an object using a constructor parameters should be passed as arguments(If not default constructor will be called)** and etc.
 Please refer [This link](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_classes.asp) to get more idea about java classes and objects.